# UIDatePicker issue on 31st December

Tags: ios5, nsdate, uidatepicker

This seems strange... I am using a UidatePicker in an actionSheet. on click of a button i display the action sheet. when i select the date as 31st December 2012 and click done, the date i get is 31st December 2013. It is happening for all the years and only on 31st December. Am i doing anything incorrect? Here is my code

```
-(void)dateButtonPressed:(id)sender //Method invoking the action sheet on button press
{
actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:nil delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil];

CGRect pickerFrame = CGRectMake(0, 40, 0, 0);

closingdatePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:pickerFrame];
closingdatePicker.tag=10;
closingdatePicker.datePickerMode=UIDatePickerModeDate;


pickerToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
pickerToolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;
[pickerToolbar sizeToFit];

NSMutableArray *barItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

UIBarButtonItem *cancelBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel target:self action:@selector(DatePickerCancelClick:)];
[barItems addObject:cancelBtn];

UIBarButtonItem *flexSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:self action:nil];
[barItems addObject:flexSpace];

UIBarButtonItem *doneBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(DatePickerDoneClick:)];
[barItems addObject:doneBtn];

[pickerToolbar setItems:barItems animated:YES];

[actionSheet addSubview:pickerToolbar];
[actionSheet addSubview:closingdatePicker];
[actionSheet showInView:self.view];
[closingdatePicker release];
[actionSheet setBounds:CGRectMake(0,0,320, 464)];
[actionSheet release];
}

- (void)DatePickerDoneClick:(id)sender{    //doen click and my date is stored in selectedDate
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/YYYY"];

//Gets our picker
UIDatePicker *ourDatePicker = (UIDatePicker *) [actionSheet viewWithTag:10];

NSDate *selectedDate = [ourDatePicker date];

closingDate.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[formatter stringFromDate:selectedDate]];

[actionSheet dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

just use **yyyy** instead of **YYYY** this  happens some time with dateformater

Comment: It is a bit late but can you explain the reason why it happens on upper case? Thanks for the answer.